# preg_match - console.log removing

Tags: php, preg-match

This is the scenario:

1. JS file is loaded into string using file_get_contents
2. I want to remove all debugging info from it
3. For the purpose of finding out whats happening in PHP code I am
   using **preg_match**

I'm using this expression:

```
(\/\/)?(\s*?)console\.(log|debug|info|log|warn|error|assert|dir|dirxml|trace|group|groupEnd|time|timeEnd|profile|profileEnd|count)\((.*?[^}(])\);?$
```

On [regex101](https://regex101.com) and [phpliveregex](http://www.phpliveregex.com) websites it matches:

```
//console.log(abc)
//   console.log(abc)
// console.log(abc);
// console.log('abc');
console.log(abc);
console.log('abc' + some_function());
etc...
```

But when I put it in PHP code like this:

```
preg_match('/(\/\/)?(\s*?)console\.(log|debug|info|log|warn|error|assert|dir|dirxml|trace|group|groupEnd|time|timeEnd|profile|profileEnd|count)\((.*?[^}(])\);?$/', $js_code, $matches);
if (!empty($matches[0])) print_r($matches[0]);
```

I dont get any matches. Too tired to notice what am I missing. Probably something staring at me with its big eyes. :)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further investigation I improved my regex pattern to match every combination.

@Jan

Your answer pushed me in the right direction.

```
((\/\/)?(\s*?)console\.(log|debug|info|log|warn|error|assert|dir|dirxml|trace|group|groupEnd|time|timeEnd|profile|profileEnd|count)(\s*?)\((.*[^}(])(\){1,});?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? Do you need this distinctuation between the different functions (`log`, etc.) ? The following regex matches all of your above examples. See a [working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ0aR4/2) here.

```
$regex = '/(?<console>(?:\/\/)?\s*console\.[^;]+;)/g';
# captured group named console with two forward slashes optionally
# followed by whitespaces (or not)
# match console. literally then anything up to a semicolon

preg_match_all($regex, $js_string, $matches);
print_r($matches["console"]);
```

**As per your comment**, if you need to match the actual method name as well, you could alter the regex like so:

```
$regex = '/(?<console>(?:\/\/)?\s*console\.(?<function>[^(]+)[^;]+;)/g';
```

Now `$matches["function"]` hold the actual method name, see [a demo for this here](https://regex101.com/r/aQ0aR4/3).

Comment: Quite nice simplification. :)
Yes, I need different variants like log, warn etc.
What I found out during PHP debugging process is that in some lines there is this kind of console.log:

console.log(fdv + some_function()) });

Notice the closure of some previous function at the end. I dont want that part removed.

Comment: @BeeEm To capture the method name as well, see my updated answer.

Comment: I think that you didn't understand me good. Sorry for the confusion I caused. I don't need to get the function name, I want to remove all variants of debugging info like console.log, console.warn etc. Thats why I have (log|warn|info|debug|error). That kind of line can have // or not at the beginning. Console.log doesn't need to end with semicolon. JS code can be messy and it can happen to have this line: console.warn('something') }); Your regex would match everything up to semicolon thus effectively leaving closure open somewhere in JS code which would produce syntax errors at least.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did to approach your problem.  Hopefully it works for you.

```
// DEFINE THE STRING
$string = "
<br>Other Text Goes Here
//console.log(abc)
//   console.log(abc)
// console.log(abc);
// console.log('abc');
<br>More Text Here
console.log(abc);
console.warn('abc' + some_function());
console.log('abc' + some_function());
<br>And More Text Goes Here";

// DO THE PREG_MATCH_ALL TO FIND ALL OCCURRENCES
preg_match_all('~(?://)?\s*console\.[A-Z]+\(.*?$~sim', $string, $matches);
print "<pre>"; print_r($matches[0]); print "</pre>";
```

That will give you the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => //console.log(abc)
    [1] => //   console.log(abc)
    [2] => // console.log(abc);
    [3] => // console.log('abc');
    [4] => 
console.log(abc);
    [5] => 
console.warn('abc' + some_function());
    [6] => 
console.log('abc' + some_function());
)
```

Finding them is one thing, but not too different from actually replacing the occurrences of it with an empty string.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
print preg_replace('~((?://)?\s*console\.[A-Z]+\(.*?$)~sim', '', $string);
```

That will show this in the browser:

```
Other Text Goes Here
More Text Here
And More Text Goes Here
```

Here is a working demo for you to take a look at:

http://ideone.com/Vv0cGY

Explanation:

`(?://)?\s*console\.[A-Z]+\(.*?$`

- `(?://)?` - Look for an optional two forward slashes.  The `?:` in front tells it to find it, but don't remember it.
- `\s*` - Look for any spaces that may or may not be present.
- `console\.[A-Z]+` - Will match `console`, followed by a literal dot `.`, followed by at least one alpha character.
- `\(.*?$` - Find an open parenthesis and grab everything up through the end of the line.

Comment: Simplified, but doesnt cover some possible occurrences properly. Consider this line:

console.log("actual: " + getActualPreTop()) });

Your pattern would match it all the way to the end which would produce errors.